# Como instalar o newtonsoft no visual studio sem o nuget

Tags: visual-studio

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para instalar o newtonsoft-json no Visual Studio sem o nuget, pois ouvi falar que daria para instalá-lo sem o nuget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma alternativa é fazer checkout do repositório, e compilar você mesmo, e adicionar a referência no seu projeto... assim fica tudo bem manual mesmo.

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json

Você pode até incluir todo o projeto dele, na sua solução, e fazer referência de projeto se quiser.

Ou ainda, pode fazer download da DLL já compilada e fazer referência à mesma, através do link abaixo:

http://james.newtonking.com/json